# How are React apps structured?

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting started with React and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the actual "flow" of a project.

I've googled and searched around on this site regarding the structure or architecture of a React app, but most of them address *file structure* and often end with some variant of "**There's no one right way to structure the files**".

But I'm looking for something more high level than that. I'm just trying to grasp how all the pieces React provides fit together. I can't even begin worrying about how I organize my files if I don't even know entirely how each file relates to one another.

As an example of what I mean - when working with an MVC app, you have three "high level" components: model, view, and controller. Their purposes and relationships to each other are distinct. A view handles the display, a model handles the data, a controller handles the connection between them. You can find easy reference diagrams to keep track of this organization.

Of course React isn't it's own paradigm, and I know it's entirely focused on front-end, but I'm curious if there's a similar way of describing the pieces of a typical React app. How containers, components, reducers, actions, etc. all work together to make an end result.

Comment: I would interpret what react docs say as "don't overthink it". When the project grows large enough, you can refactor it to move parts around. Chances are you'll want to do that at some point, so don't stress about it in the beginning. Another benefit with this is that with time, you'll learn more and have a better understanding of what's what, how to name it, and where to place it. First, focus on what matters: learning and understanding React.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Marko Grešak's comment. You learn as you do and understand the code.

But, if you fill lost (which I was also), I can tell you about some architectures I saw :

- A teacher of mine split the logic and the view. In one folder, you find your components, in one folder, classic JS classes that contains all the functions that handle the logic behind what the components print. Each component imported its own css file, with only the styles for this one component. We used this with MobX..
- At work, we have a js folder, containing a components folder, for components that are at the 'end of the line', a containers folder, for components that have other components in them, a store folder for everything Redux, an asset folder for images and such, and a utility folder for other functions we might want to call. At the same level as the js folder, we have a sass folder. This is in no way a 'correct' or 'recommanded' way of doing things.
- In general, you'll find a lot of tutorials and other things referring to dumb and smart components - splitting between the ones that just receive props and print them, and the ones accessing data and manipulating it. It's a bit like our container/component system in the end.

In the end, you're free to do how you want. Just try to keep a certain logic in how you split things so that it makes sense overall, but there is no set rules.